# My viewport movement is inverted and strange

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

I'm not sure what I did but when I rotate my view in the viewport, it's like it's inverted or rotating around another object offset from the one I've selected. Any ideas as to what I did to cause this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have enabled the option called "Lock to 3D cursor", which can be found by pressing 'n' to get the side bar and clicking on the "view" tab.

Comment: Hello :). Nice Q and A. If you find the time, you can also add some images to better illustrate the answer.